Expose only first n records from data frame and create a summary row for the remaining records
I have a list of companies with some business results. I need to create a resulting table  where would be exposed only first n (say 3) companies with the highest market share and the business results of the remaining companies would be included into the last row as a summary.
The example df:
  df <- tibble(
    company = paste0("company_", LETTERS)[1:5],
    var1 = c(150, 200, 320, 800, 450),
    market_share = c(.2, .05, .45, .25, .05)
  )
  
  df

#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   company    var1 market_share
#>   <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 company_A   150         0.2 
#> 2 company_B   200         0.05
#> 3 company_C   320         0.45
#> 4 company_D   800         0.25
#> 5 company_E   450         0.05

Created on 2024-10-02 with reprex v2.1.1
I want to alter this df in the following way:

arrange records in descending order by column market_share,
expose - show only first 3 records - companies with the biggest market share,
generate a summary row for remaining companies as follows:

"Company" column would contain text "Rest" and number of remaining companies in bracket,
"var1" column would be an average value from the remaining 2 records/companies,
"market_share" column would contain the sum of market shares of remaining 2 records/companies



So the resulting data frame would have only 4 rows, first three companies with the biggest market share and then the summary row for the remaining 2 companies.
It would look like this:
  df_result <- tribble(
    ~company, ~var1, ~market_share,
    "company_C", 320, .45,
    "company_D", 800, .25,
    "company_A", 150, .2,
    "Rest (2)", 325, 0.1
  )

  df_result
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   company    var1 market_share
#>   <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 company_C   320         0.45
#> 2 company_D   800         0.25
#> 3 company_A   150         0.2 
#> 4 Rest (2)    325         0.1

Created on 2024-10-02 with reprex v2.1.1
How can I achieve this please?

library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(
    rank = rank(-market_share, ties.method = "first"),
    rank = ifelse(rank <= 3, rank, Inf)
  ) |>
  summarize(
    company = if(n() > 1) sprintf("Rest (%d)", n()) else company,
    across(c(var1, market_share), sum),
    .by = rank
  ) |>
  arrange(rank)
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#    rank company    var1 market_share
#   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1 company_C   320         0.45
# 2     2 company_D   800         0.25
# 3     3 company_A   150         0.2 
# 4   Inf Rest (2)    650         0.1 


With splits and purrr::map_at():
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(
  company = paste0("company_", LETTERS)[1:5],
  var1 = c(150, 200, 320, 800, 450),
  market_share = c(.2, .05, .45, .25, .05)
)


df |> 
  arrange(desc(market_share)) |> 
  # split by rank condition
  split(~rev(rank(market_share, ties.method = "first")) > 3) |> 
  # modify "TRUE" split
  map_at("TRUE", \(x) summarise(x, company = str_glue("Rest ({n()})"),
                                   var1 = mean(var1),
                                   market_share = sum(market_share))) |> 
  # bind back together
  bind_rows()

#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   company    var1 market_share
#>   <glue>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 company_C   320         0.45
#> 2 company_D   800         0.25
#> 3 company_A   150         0.2 
#> 4 Rest (2)    325         0.1

Splits:
#> $`FALSE`
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   company    var1 market_share
#>   <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 company_C   320         0.45
#> 2 company_D   800         0.25
#> 3 company_A   150         0.2 
#> 
#> $`TRUE`
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   company    var1 market_share
#>   <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 company_B   200         0.05
#> 2 company_E   450         0.05

Created on 2024-10-02 with reprex v2.1.1

Another approach using a helper group that combines all companies below the third.
library(dplyr)

rec <- 3

df %>%
  arrange(desc(market_share)) %>%
  mutate(grp = c(seq_len(rec), rep(rec + 1, n() - rec))) %>%
  summarize(company = ifelse(n() > 1, paste0("Rest ","(",n(),")"), company[1]),
            var1 = mean(var1), 
            market_share = sum(market_share), .by = grp) %>%
  select(-grp)

output
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  company    var1 market_share
  <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1 company_C   320         0.45
2 company_D   800         0.25
3 company_A   150         0.2
4 Rest (2)    325         0.1


A simple approach in base R
df0 = as.data.frame(df)
rbind(df0[seq(3), ], 
      c(company = paste0("Rest (", nrow(df0)-3L, ")"), 
        vapply(df0[-seq(3), -1], sum, numeric(1L)))) |>
  `row.names<-`(NULL)

giving
    company var1 market_share
1 company_C  320         0.45
2 company_D  800         0.25
3 company_A  150          0.2
4  Rest (2)  650          0.1

